# How to filter the options of a drop down list using another drop down list asp.net core 3.0

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, drop-down-menu

I would like to select a product category in one drop-down list and display subcategories for it.
My models:
ProductCategory

```
        public class ProductCategory
            {
                [Key]
                public int Id { get; set; }
        
                [Required(ErrorMessage ="Pole 'Nazwa kategorii' jest wymagane")]
                [Display(Name ="Nazwa kategorii")]
                public string Name { get; set; }
        
                [Display(Name = "Dodaj zdjęcie")]
                public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        
                public virtual ICollection<ProductSubCategory> ProductSubCategory { get; set; }
        
            }
```

ProductSubCategory

```
public class ProductSubCategory
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pole 'Nazwa podkategorii' jest wymagane")]
        [Display(Name = "Nazwa kategorii")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    
        [Display(Name = "Wybierz zdjęcie")]
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    
        public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    
        [ForeignKey("ProductCategoryId")]
        [Display(Name = "Kategoria")]
        public ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
    
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

Create Product Page

```
    public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            ViewData["ProductCategoryId"] = new SelectList(_context.ProductCategory, "Id", "Name");
            ViewData["ProductSubCategoryId"] = new SelectList(_context.ProductSubCategory, "Id", "Name");
            return Page();
        }
        public JsonResult OnGetSubCategories(int category)
        {
            var subcategories = _context.ProductSubCategory.Where(c => c.ProductCategoryId == category).ToList();
            return new JsonResult(new SelectList(subcategories, "Id", "Name"));
        }
```

CreateProduct html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Product.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Product.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Product.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Product.Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Product.Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Product.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Product.ImagePath" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="file" asp-for="Product.ImagePath" class="form-control" name="image" onchange="readURL(this);"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Product.ImagePath" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Product.DateOfNotification" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Product.DateOfNotification" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Product.DateOfNotification" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Product.ProductCategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select id="category" asp-for="Product.ProductCategoryId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ProductCategoryId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Product.ProductSubCategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select id="subCategory" asp-for="Product.ProductSubCategoryId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ProductSubCategoryId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

```
        script
            <script>
            $("#category").change(function () {
            var category = $("#category").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "CreteProduct?handler=SubCategories",
                method: "GET",
                data: { category: category },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#subCategory option").remove();
                    $.each(data, function (index, itemData) {       
                        $("#subCategory").append("<option value='" + itemData.Id + "'>" + itemData.Name + "</option>");
                    });
                }
            })
        });
        </script>
```

Result: The subcategory drop-down list is undefined. After selecting the category the number of items is good but displays 'undefined'.

[image]

Comment: What exactly does *"drop-down list is undefined"* mean and where is it undefined?

Comment: The values ​​are displayed as undefined. The number of items is correct

Comment: So what does a sample object in data look like?

Comment: int Id; string Name

Comment: That doesn't reflect the javascript object you are parsing get that `undefined` from. The structure received is clearly different than what you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `itemData.value` to replace `itemData.Id`,`itemData.text` to replace `itemData.Name`.Here is a demo worked:

cshtml.cs:

```
public class CreateProductModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public static List<ProductCategory> productCategories = new List<ProductCategory> { new ProductCategory { Id = 1, Name = "pc1" }, new ProductCategory { Id = 2, Name = "pc2" } };
        public static List<ProductSubCategory> productSubCategories = new List<ProductSubCategory> { new ProductSubCategory { Id = 11, Name = "psc11", ProductCategoryId = 1 }, new ProductSubCategory { Id = 12, Name = "psc12", ProductCategoryId = 1 }, new ProductSubCategory { Id = 21, Name = "psc21", ProductCategoryId = 2 }, new ProductSubCategory { Id = 22, Name = "psc22", ProductCategoryId = 2 } };
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            ViewData["ProductCategoryId"] = new SelectList(productCategories, "Id", "Name");
            ViewData["ProductSubCategoryId"] = new SelectList(productSubCategories, "Id", "Name");
            return Page();
        }
        public JsonResult OnGetSubCategories(int category)
        {
            var subcategories = productSubCategories.Where(p => p.ProductCategoryId == category).ToList();
            return new JsonResult(new SelectList(subcategories, "Id", "Name"));
        }

    }
```

cshtml:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Product.Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Product.Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Product.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Product.Description" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Product.Description" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Product.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Product.ImagePath" class="control-label"></label>
        <input type="file" asp-for="Product.ImagePath" class="form-control" name="image" onchange="readURL(this);" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Product.ImagePath" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Product.DateOfNotification" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Product.DateOfNotification" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Product.DateOfNotification" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Product.ProductCategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select id="category" asp-for="Product.ProductCategoryId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ProductCategoryId"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Product.ProductSubCategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select id="subCategory" asp-for="Product.ProductSubCategoryId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ProductSubCategoryId"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
@section scripts{ 
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#category").change(function () {
                var category = $("#category").val();
                $.ajax({
                url: "CreateProduct?handler=SubCategories",
                    method: "GET",
                    data: {category: category },
                    success: function (data) {
                $("#subCategory option").remove();
                        $.each(data, function (index, itemData) {
                $("#subCategory").append("<option value='" + itemData.value + "'>" + itemData.text + "</option>");
                        });
                    }
                })
            });
</script>
}
```

result:
[image]

[image]

Comment: on console is error: CreateProduct?handler=SubCategories&category=2:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: You can see in the handler `OnGetSubCategories`,the type of category is `int`,And I updated my answer to add the request url.In your url category is 2:1 not a `int` type.

Comment: how to change this value

Comment: The value you set is in ajax `data: {category: category },`And I passed data '1' so that the  `category=1`